# is there any way to disable animation for jQuery ui-datepicker only for ie6?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery UI 1.8.11 datepicker. It works good for FF/Chrome but fails to load properly on IE6. One solution I found to make it work on IE6 is to disable the animation (i.e. showAnim: none). But it will disable animation for all other modern browsers too.

Is there any way I can disable it ONLY FOR IE6 and showAnim: "drop" for other browsers?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I dislike browser detection, if ever it's appropriate, it's for IE6.

Fortunately, JQuery does provide the tools to help you. Something like this should do the trick:

```
if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version<7) {....}
```

See the JQuery.browser manual page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: Spudley, thank you very much for your immediate reply. It worked for me.

the code below would help other people if they come across same issue:

`showAnim: ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version<7) ? null : "drop"`